# How to set background texture to 50% of the page in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to work out how to display my background texture for 50% height of the page being displayed, I am using the following code at the moment which includes a semi transparent texture that goes above a solid background colour. I want the background colour to be over the whole page but the texture to stop at 50% of the page height, but I am a bit lost on how to do it, is this a new css3 function ?, if so are there any work around's for other browsers or jquery alternatives if this wont work with older browsers ?.

```
body {
background: url(../images/light/background.png) repeat scroll 0 0 #832029;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the idea of 50% the height is the best approach.

Try this:

```
body{
  background-color: #832029;
  background-image: url(../images/light/background.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Resizing background images (which you are not currently doing) is a CSS3 function which is not supported by all browsers, so a fixed image height (300-400 or so pixels) would probably be best.

Comment: Thanks that works :-) , why do you think having the background as 50% is not a good approach ?.

Comment: background-size is supported by all current browsers... http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: @WouterJ: Gotta support IE8 (and IE7...).

Comment: @Derek, then you can use the [IE filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For CSS3 there is [`background-size`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#the-background-size) property and it has support in all major browsers, IE9+ and Opera 10+. And for IE8 and lower there is a [IE Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Make 2 background images. One image is the gradient (which can be done with [CSS3: `linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient) too) and the second image is the texture. Use [multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) and set only a background-size on the texture background image.

---

If you wouldn't use this CSS3 property you can solve it with HTML and CSS only. Make a div inside the  called #background. And with CSS give it an absolute position and a height of 50%:

```
#background
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; // place it on the lowest layer
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 50%; left: 0;
  background: url('path/to/images/background.png') repeat scroll #832029;
}
```